# Store Locator: Google Maps Not Displaying

Tags: google-api, locations

I am using `Magento Community Ver. 1.9.0.1` and tried to implement the Store / Dealer locator extension.
Link to Extension in Magento Connect: `http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/store-dealer-locator.html`

I registered as a developer on Google and got the Google API for Google Maps and created the Google API Url.

My problem is my stores show on the store locator page but the map does not.
Link to Store Locator page: `http://hi-schoolworld.com/datta_storelocator/`

I tried embedding a Google Map in a page to test whether my API Url was incorrect but that map is showing up just fine.
Link to Embedded Map example: I've exceeded my link limit...Click on Store Locator in the top navigation (hi-schoolworld dot com /map)

I have tried contacting the developer without success so now I turn to the community...Help me StackExchange, you're my only hope!

Comment: Your google maps api error msg is

`The Google Maps API server rejected your request. Invalid request. Invalid 'q' parameter`.

Comment: It seems that the problem lies in my Google API Url. When I enter the Url as depicted in the example screenshot I receive an error message "Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. This site is not authorized to use the Google Maps client ID provided...." I am researching this in Google's help. Where were you able to see that api error msg?

Comment: To debug using chrome inspect element. Error `The Google Maps API server rejected your request. Invalid request. Missing the 'q' parameter.`

Comment: I'm going to close this thread since it seems to be more of a Google issue than a Magento issue but before I do, is there anyone that can point me to where to learn more about this issue? I believe my API Url is incorrect. If I use the one given in the example: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3 I receive an error message that the site isn't authorized to use the Google Maps client ID provided. I am a newbie when it comes to Google APIs so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What url did you enter into google admin (`http://www.site.com` or `http://site.com`) also take a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/troubleshooting_auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*** PROBLEM SOLVED ***

It's embarrassing to admit but it was as simple as turning on the correct service. In Google's API Console I had initiated "Google Maps Embed API" instead of "Google Maps JavaScript API v3".

I'll keep this thread open on the random chance someone else encounters this problem. Thank you so much for all your time and help!

P.S. How-To Guide: `developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial`